# Uncaught ReferenceError: PrimeFaces is not defined

Tags: java, bootstrap, jsf, primefaces

Estoy usando **primefaces** y **bootstrap** en un login y obtengo el siguiente error:

> ```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>     at login.xhtml:252
> (anonymous) @ login.xhtml:252 login.xhtml:260 
> Uncaught ReferenceError: PrimeFaces is not defined
>     at login.xhtml:260
> (anonymous) @ login.xhtml:260
> ```

He probado a incluir la hoja de estilos en la cabecera, a incluir una versión de jquery distinta... nada me funciona!!!

Adjunto código de login.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>

</h:head>

<h:body style="text-align:center">
    <p:growl id="mensajes" showDetail="true" life="2000" />
    <h:form>
        <p:panel header="Login" style="width:300px">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Usuario:" />
                <p:inputText value="#{loginBean.nombreUsu}" id="username"
                    required="true" label="username" />
                <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Clave:" />
                <p:password value="#{loginBean.password}" id="password" required="true"
                    label="password" />
                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Login"
                        actionListener="#{loginBean.submit}" update=":mensajes"
                        oncomplete="manejarLogin(xhr, status, args)" />
                </f:facet>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
</h:body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[ 
    function manejarLogin(xhr, status, args) {
        if (!args.validationFailed && args.estaLogeado) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location = args.view;
            }, 500);
        }
    }
    //]]>
</script>
</html>
```

EDITO:

Acabo de darme cuenta de que algunos documentos propios de primefaces cargan en estado 302... esto por qué ocurre???

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estoy seguro de que puedes poner un ejemplo mucho más mínimo que aún sea completo y verificable([mcve]), porque se hace muy difícil seguir varios cientos de líneas de código. En todo caso, esto no tiene nada que ver con bootstrap, es una cuestión de primefaces (¿quizás no está la librería deployada?)

Comment: Acabo de modificar el código para incluir un ejemplo más básico y sencillo de interpretar. El resultado del error es el mismo. Esto ocurre al abrir el login por primera vez tras arrancar Tomcat 8.0. El login lo realiza correctamente y si hago logout entonces si que carga bien primefaces. La versión de primefaces es la 6.1.RC1 y se encuentra en el pom.

Comment: 302 no es un problema *en principio*, sólo indica que el servidor le ha hecho una redirección ("esta URL no es, busca en esta otra que te paso"). Pero está redireccionando a páginas .xhtml para lo que deberían ser recursos estáticos. Y más abajo, al hacer la redirección, aunque reciben un código 200 todas las conexiones tienen el mismo tamaño (3.7KB), ¿puedes poner el contenido que recibes? Yo apuntaría a un problema de configuración de JSF; posiblemente el filtro de URLs asignados al servlet JSF (¿quizás has metido `/*`?)

Comment: tienes el código de ese controlador, tengo el mismo error y no he podido solucionarlo, lo digo porque no se que objeto es el path.
De antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale, me contesto yo mismo...

Tengo un filtro para el login y hay que incorporar `path.startsWith("/javax.faces.resource/")` porque si no, no encuentra jQuery y otras carpetas y no arranca correctamente.

Adjunto código:

```
if(usuario != null || path.equals("/login") || path.equals("/login.xhtml") 
  || path.startsWith("/public/") || path.equals("/favicon.ico")
  || path.startsWith("/javax.faces.resource/")){

    if(usuario != null && path.equals("/login.xhtml")){
        res.sendRedirect("/inicio.xhtml");
    }else{
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}else{
    res.sendRedirect("login.xhtml");
}
```

Si no hacemos esto de esta manera, no carga correctamente.

Comment: Me alegra que encontraras solucion. pero las respuestas tienen que tener cierta calidad. Mira [answer].Responde como si fuera la pregunta de otor usuario y no la tuya. Un saludo